# AppleUSBCDC weirdness after strange incident

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb

I use my MBP propped on one of those laptop stands, ergo my external USB mouse and USB keyboard (both generic cheap-ass Logitechs) are always connected through a powered Belkin USB hub.

Yesterday I noticed the following — after trying to eject my iPod, my USB mouse started “slowing down”, the pointer wasn’t moving smoothly. Then both the mouse and the keyboard stopped working, the “laser” in the mouse went off. I noticed that the hub became extremely (!) hot and unplugged it. This is how it happened log-wise:

```
05.01.12 00:55:11,000 kernel: USBF: 29136.223   [0xffffff800b871e00] The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 7 of Hub at 0xfd120000)
05.01.12 00:55:29,000 kernel: USBF: 29154.870   AppleUSBHubPort[0xffffff800b86e000]::FatalError - Port 6 of Hub at 0xfd120000 reported error 0xe000404f while doing get status (second in port status change)
05.01.12 00:55:44,000 kernel: Logitech USB Keyboard::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous) timeout
05.01.12 00:55:44,000 kernel: USBF: 29169.943   AppleUSBHubPort[0xffffff800b871e00]::FatalError - Port 7 of Hub at 0xfd120000 reported error 0xe00002c0 while doing clearing port feature (1)
05.01.12 00:55:46,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 00:55:46,000 kernel: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000A2700150DF0AA 0x5ac 0x1209 0x2
05.01.12 00:55:46,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 00:55:46,000 kernel: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 574341535531333731343832 0x1058 0x1001 0x106
05.01.12 00:55:46,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 00:55:54,000 kernel: IOUSBMassStorageClass[0xffffff800cc3e600]: The device is still unresponsive after 6 consecutive USB Device Resets; it will be terminated.
05.01.12 00:55:54,000 kernel: USBF: 29179.967   [0xffffff800cc3ee00] The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 7 of Hub at 0xfd120000)
05.01.12 00:56:03,000 kernel: USBF: 29188.734   [0xffffff800cc3ee00] The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
05.01.12 00:56:04,000 kernel: USBF: 29189.636   [0xffffff800cc3aa00] The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 5 of Hub at 0xfd120000)
05.01.12 00:56:19,000 kernel: USB Optical Mouse::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous) timeout
05.01.12 00:56:19,000 kernel: USBF: 29205.  7   AppleUSBHubPort[0xffffff800cc3aa00]::FatalError - Port 5 of Hub at 0xfd120000 reported error 0xe00002ed while doing get status (first in port status change)
05.01.12 00:56:19,000 kernel: USBF: 29205.  7   [0xffffff800cc3aa00] The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
05.01.12 00:56:36,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 00:56:36,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 01:00:41,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 01:00:41,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
```

When I plug the mouse and the keyboard directly into the two built-in USB ports, everything works fine. I’m using the Belkin hub again, and so far it’s not heating up, everything works. However, every time I connect USB peripherals (=my mouse and keyboard), no matter if it’s the Belkin hub or one the built-in ports, I get something like that:

```
05.01.12 13:18:55,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 13:18:55,000 kernel: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 574341535531333731343832 0x1058 0x1001 0x106
05.01.12 13:18:55,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
05.01.12 13:18:55,000 kernel: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
```

Mind you, everything works, and so far I haven’t encountered the “jerky mouse” problem or USB timeouts again. What’s going on? Is this normal? Have I somehow fried my Mac’s USB? :(

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the exact product? Belkin sells conventional usb hubs, as well as network usb hubs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have anything to be worried about.

The AppleUSBCDC mentioned in the error message is related to "communication devices". This is usually a USB<>Ethernet adapter. Do you have such a device plugged in?

Try unplugging it and rebooting your system - I guess that will make the error messages disappear.